# Error with firebase starting project on vue2

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2

When I run `npm run dev`, get next error
I write on Vue 2 webpack-simple, firebase 9.9.0
Tried npm firebase@^9.9.0 but no result
main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import {Vuelidate} from "vuelidate";
import {firestorePlugin} from "vuefire";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(firestorePlugin)

import {store} from "../store";
import {router} from "./plugins/routes"


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "***"
};

export const db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()

const {Timestamp, GeoPoint} = firebase.firestore()
export {Timestamp, GeoPoint}

db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**Error**

```
./node_modules/idb/build/index.js
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (83:4)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | }
    | replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
    |     ...oldTraps,
    |     get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
    |     has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),
     @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 5:0-29
     @ ./node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js
     @ ./src/main.js
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to update vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot of things including downgrading firebase, upgrading vue-cli, installing @vue/cli none of which worked for me.

finally tried
`npm rebuild firebase` which just worked.

P.S. I am not sure but this error is a generic message of vue when it can't resolve an object property or method. It is not specific to firebase and you can see it in a lot of other cases.